Why a relay frequently clicks when a battery is low?
Shouldn't the starter relay be closed while a car is starting? Why does it open/close frequently when key is turned, making a repeated clicking sound?
Does the relay behave this way only in the low battery case or it clicks always while a car is starting, but clicks are not audible due to the working starter noise?

If the battery is low, the starter solenoid may still receive enough voltage to move its armature against spring tension and close its contacts to send battery current to the starter motor. However, as soon as the starter is energized, the current drain is so great that the voltage at the starter relay falls below the level required for the armature to overcome spring tension, and its contacts open.
As soon as the contacts open, the starter ends its current drain and the voltage at the starter relay returns to a level high enough to move its armature against spring tension and close its contacts to send battery current to the starter motor.
Rinse and repeat, many times per second.

Then shouldn't the starter shaft popping in/out sound be present there at the same time? It should be even loader due of the metal parts involvement as the flywheel, shaft gear and solenoid. Does this sound present in this video for example?

@MiniMax In the referenced video, the car begins with enough battery to extend the starter's spur gear and start cranking, but as cranking continues to consume battery power, the voltage drops low enough that the starter relay is unable to keep its contacts closed against spring tension. That's when the relay chattering begins as described above, and it continues until the driver releases the key. After a pause, the battery recovers a little and can crank again. The cycle repeats. In every case, it's all about insufficient voltage to keep the starter relay's contacts closed.

This condition is actually the same method used in cheap electric buzzers.

@barbecue car horns used to work that way also, vibrating at hundreds of Hertz. I made a horn like that when I was a child. Electromagnetism is amazing!

If the battery voltage is too low, the relay may not get enough power to stay closed. Instead, it opens and closes rapidly as it tries to engage, resulting in the clicking sound.  The frequent clicking of the starter relay usually indicates insufficient voltage or current from the battery. In a healthy system, the relay should engage smoothly without audible clicks. If you notice this behavior, it’s advisable to check the battery's charge and the condition of the electrical connections.
